# JavaScript String.replace() all instances and escaping

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a string: `Dkjd(Dk39dD_2=3499(39482&#6293jd`

I would like to escape all characters of my choosing (say, `_#-`) with a backslash. I'm confused how I would do this with `String.replace`. Can I use the original value in the new value var? Can I use RegEx to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use function, use backreference:

```
source.replace(/([_#\-])/g, "\\$1")
```

The thing in parentheses can be referenced as `$1` in replacement string.

Comment: I knew there was something like that! Perfect.

Comment: Well, sometimes escaping more tricky than putting a backslash; in that case one must use a function like here: https://github.com/amber-smalltalk/amber/blob/0.12.3/st/Kernel-Collections.st#L1502

Answer (score 3):

This should be easy with a regex.

```
var str = 'Dkjd(Dk39dD_2=3499(39482&#6293jd';
str = str.replace(/[_#-]/g, function(match){
    return '\\'+match;
});

console.log(str); // Dkjd(Dk39dD\_2=3499(39482&\#6293jd
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply,

```
var str = 'Dkjd(Dk39dD_2=3499(39482&#6293jd';

str = str.replace(/([_#-])/g, '\\$1');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your regex should be `/([_#-])/g`, otherwise there are no capture groups.

Comment: This is better than my answer.  You don't need a function, just backreferences :-)